# Ng-bootstrap datepicker is not styled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, datepicker

I'm working with Angular 4.4.6 and rails 5.1.4

I'm going to use datepicker from [ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/examples)

Firstly, I created the folder `app/javascript/DatePicker` and its files 
`app/javascript/DatePicker/datepicker-basic.html` and `app/javascript/DatePicker/index.ts.`

Then, inserted the code from the resource to these files changing the path to the template.

```
// app/javascript/DatePicker/index.ts

import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NgbDateStruct} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

import template from './datepicker-basic.html'

const now = new Date();

@Component({
  selector: 'ngbd-datepicker-basic',
  template: template
})
export class NgbdDatepickerBasic {

model: NgbDateStruct;
date: {year: number, month: number};

selectToday() {
    this.model = {year: now.getFullYear(), month: now.getMonth() + 1, 
day: now.getDate()};
  }
}

// app/javascript/DatePicker/datepicker-basic.html

<p>Simple datepicker</p>

<ngb-datepicker #dp [(ngModel)]="model" (navigate)="date = $event.next">
</ngb-datepicker>
<hr/>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" 
       (click)="selectToday()">
  Select Today
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" 
        (click)="dp.navigateTo()">
  To current month
</button>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary" 
              (click)="dp.navigateTo({year: 2013, month: 2})">
  To Feb 2013
</button>
<hr/>
<pre>Month: {{ date.month }}.{{ date.year }}</pre>
<pre>Model: {{ model | json }}</pre>
```

Then in app/javascript/customers.js I added

```
import { NgbdDatepickerBasic } from "../DatePicker/index";
import {NgbModule} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

.........


var CustomerAppModule = NgModule({
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,

    NgbModule.forRoot(),

    routing
],
declarations: [
    CustomerSearchComponent,
    CustomerDetailsComponent,
    CustomerInfoComponent,
    TextFieldComponent,
    FilterByPipe,

    NgbdDatepickerBasic,

    AppComponent
],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
```

Finally, i added tag

```
<ngbd-modal-basic></ngbd-modal-basic>
```

to the page where I want to see the datepicker

The calendar has appeared and it works, but the problem is that it was placed into a whole page.  The Days are placed one column at the bottom of the page. That is, CSS styles were not applied to the calendar.

What I'm doing wrong? Can anybody help me?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and include bootstrap.css to your project from http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: update of bootstrap from 3 to 4.0.0-beta2 via yarn did help